# Figure caption runs off page

Tags: floats, captions

How can I get latex to place my figure sufficiently at the top of my page to allow for my caption to nicely fit at the bottom?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\makebox[\textwidth]{
  \centering
  \includegraphics{./Figures/chapter7/rel_risk_overall_ss.pdf}}
    \caption{Comparing average risk during care to 3 uninfected patients within single and multibed room relative to \emph{direct care}.  $\alpha=0.069$. }
  \label{fig:rel_risk}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

Comment: you can tweak the size of the included graphics with `totalheight` or `width` options, for example `\includegraphics[totalheight=17cm]` `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]`. Any of these two commands will keep the aspect ratio of the figure.

Comment: Ahh yes this looks good! `totalheight` will not scale the figure then?

Comment: As far as i recall, `totalheight` will scale the figure (keeping the aspect ratio). I think that you could specify both width and height using both options at the same time, and the image aspect ratio will change. There is also the `scale` option which can be useful in your case.

Comment: I used to use scale assiduously but don't want the font size of my figures to change noticeably. I really just want my figure to fit on the page by placing the float closer to the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your figure is too large (in height) and you should get a warning when compiling. The geometry package can show you the actual available space with `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`. Usually figures are centred vertically on a page if there is no other content. You can align them at the top with

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hmm quite possibly. Where do I paste your code?

Comment: it needs to go before `\begin{document}` to affect your whole document. Did you check your page size with the geometry package, did you check for warnings in the log-file?